# Magento 2 : Get collection of based on field

Tags: magento2, collection

Here is the collection I have as an output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [rma_id] => 1
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => CA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2
            [rma_id] => 2
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => DE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 3
            [rma_id] => 3
            [product_sku] => 26-MB02
            [subsidiary] => DE
        )

)
```

In this, I want to have records with the same SKU but different subsidiaries only.

Desired output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [rma_id] => 1
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => CA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2
            [rma_id] => 2
            [product_sku] => 24-MB02
            [subsidiary] => DE
        )
 )
```

You see the same product_sku but a different subsidiary.

here is the code.

```
$rmaCollection = $_objectManager->create('Mirasvit\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory'); //avoid object manager use while development.

$collection = $rmaCollection->create()->load();

print_r($collection->getData());
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this 3rd party extension, but I'll talk about how to it work in general

```php
// this part means you create collection factory
$factory = $_objectManager->create('Mirasvit\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory');

// this part means you create new collection instance
$collection = $factory->create();

// next you may need to add filters
$collection->addFieldToFilter('field', ['eq' => 'some_value']);

// next you can set your order
$collection->setOrder('subsidiary', \Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC);

// next you can set some limits, by default without limits
$collection->setPageSize(100);

// this means you load 
// you don't need to load data if you are going to use getData method
// collection will be loaded automatically when you'll iterate it
$collection->load();

// You can use collection in 2 ways:
// 1. Use objects
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    // do something with item
    // item is instance of related model
}

// 2. Use RAW with getData method
foreach ($collection->getData() as $item) {
    // do something with item
    // item is array
}

// Note: If you will be use both ways on the same collection the data will be loaded twice
```

Comment: Hi Victor, I am trying to prevent having duplicate values for product SKU in list considering only one row of SKU for one subsidiary ?

Comment: In this case better to create your own collection and specify request. As workaround you can use `$collection->getSelect()` method to get Select object and use some like `->group('product_sku')`. Anyway, you didn't specify your end goal.

Comment: Can we have a quick chat?

Comment: advocat [at] gmail.com